# Spring Boot Refresh w/o Config server

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Is there any way to refresh spring beans/properties w/o actuator and config server?

In my case, there is only one app/instance which reads the properties from the local file system

```
myapp.sample.prop1=1
myapp.sample.prop2=2

@ConfigurationProperties("myapp.sample")
public class Prop{

  private int prop1;
  private int prop2;

}
```

I autowire and i use it,

```
@Autowired
private Prop prop;
```

Occasionally the value might change in the file system. In that case,I just want to call my custom endpoint `/reload` which should refresh the values by reading the file.

Comment: Why don't you want to use an actuator ? isn't the actuator exactly the endpoint you want for your use-case ? You don't need to have a config server to have the capability of reloading external yml files trough an actuator

Comment: I do not want unnecessary dependencies. also what if the app is not web based.? should I always expose an endpoint.? There should still be a way to do it right?

Comment: Take a look at https://www.baeldung.com/spring-reloading-properties. It might suit your needs.